# Java table.getmode.getvalueat(row, column) works in 1 method, not in other?

Tags: java, mysql

I have these 2 methods:

```
 public void Delete(){
    try{


        PreparedStatement stmt = activeConn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM lid WHERE lid_id = ?");


        int selectedID = (int) table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0);




        stmt.setInt(1, selectedID);

        stmt.executeUpdate();

        stmt.close();

    }
     catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

and

```
public int getID(){

        int id = (int) table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0);

        return id;

}
```

the first one is supposed to delete a certain row in the mysql table. It works perfectly. The second one is supposed to only give the value at the selected row at the first column(which is the id in the table). But it gives me the ""AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1" error.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to invoke:
`javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableDataChanged()`

after you have deleted a row from database.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getID(){
int Selectedrow = table.getSelectedRow();
int id = 0;
if(Selectedrow == -1){
    // No row selected
    // Show error message
}
else{
     id = (int) table.getModel().getValueAt(Selectedrow, 0);
}
return id;
}
```

you haven't selected a row from the `jtable` which is throwing the `exeption`
you need to always check if the user has selected a row before using the selected row. if the user has not selected a row you will get -1  and `jtable`
doesn't have a row with `-1`